# Highcharts error : [TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined]

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts, jsreport

I have been trying to use the Highcharts module in my javascript code to derive a PDF documents consisting charts. I have followed the example given in this page: [Highcharts link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-release) and this is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Highcharts = require('highcharts');

require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    data: [1, 3, 2, 4]
  }],
});

var jsreport = require('jsreport-core')()

jsreport.init().then(function () {     
   return jsreport.render({ 
    template:{
      content : '<div>{{:ch}}</div>',
      engine : 'jsrender',
      recipe : 'phantom-pdf'
    },
    data : {
      ch:chart
    }
    }).then(function(resp) { 
     fs.writeFile(__dirname+'/random.pdf',resp.content)
     // console.log(resp.content.toString())
   });
}).catch(function(e) {
  console.log(e)
})
```

I get the following error:

```
/home/infinite007/Documents/jsr/node_modules/highcharts/modules/exporting.js:9
(function(h){"object"===typeof module&&module.exports?module.exports=h:h(Highcharts)})(function(h){(function(f){var h=f.defaultOptions,n=f.doc,A=f.Chart,u=f.addEvent,F=f.removeEvent,D=f.fireEvent,q=f.createElement,B=f.discardElement,v=f.css,p=f.merge,C=f.pick,k=f.each,r=f.extend,G=f.isTouchDevice,E=f.win,H=f.Renderer.prototype.symbols;r(h.lang,{printChart:"Print chart",downloadPNG:"Download PNG image",downloadJPEG:"Download JPEG image",downloadPDF:"Download PDF document",downloadSVG:"Download SVG vector image",
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at /home/infinite007/Documents/jsr/node_modules/highcharts/modules/exporting.js:9:319
    at /home/infinite007/Documents/jsr/node_modules/highcharts/modules/exporting.js:26:411
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/infinite007/Documents/jsr/sample.js:4:40)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:990:3
```

[link to exporting.js](http://www.filedropper.com/exporting)

exporting.js Code:

```
/*
 Highcharts JS v5.0.6 (2016-12-07)
 Exporting module

 (c) 2010-2016 Torstein Honsi

 License: www.highcharts.com/license
*/
(function(h){"object"===typeof module&&module.exports?module.exports=h:h(Highcharts)})(function(h){(function(f){var h=f.defaultOptions,n=f.doc,A=f.Chart,u=f.addEvent,F=f.removeEvent,D=f.fireEvent,q=f.createElement,B=f.discardElement,v=f.css,p=f.merge,C=f.pick,k=f.each,r=f.extend,G=f.isTouchDevice,E=f.win,H=f.Renderer.prototype.symbols;r(h.lang,{printChart:"Print chart",downloadPNG:"Download PNG image",downloadJPEG:"Download JPEG image",downloadPDF:"Download PDF document",downloadSVG:"Download SVG vector image",
contextButtonTitle:"Chart context menu"});h.navigation={buttonOptions:{theme:{},symbolSize:14,symbolX:12.5,symbolY:10.5,align:"right",buttonSpacing:3,height:22,verticalAlign:"top",width:24}};p(!0,h.navigation,{menuStyle:{border:"1px solid #999999",background:"#ffffff",padding:"5px 0"},menuItemStyle:{padding:"0.5em 1em",background:"none",color:"#333333",fontSize:G?"14px":"11px",transition:"background 250ms, color 250ms"},menuItemHoverStyle:{background:"#335cad",color:"#ffffff"},buttonOptions:{symbolFill:"#666666",
symbolStroke:"#666666",symbolStrokeWidth:3,theme:{fill:"#ffffff",stroke:"none",padding:5}}});h.exporting={type:"image/png",url:"https://export.highcharts.com/",printMaxWidth:780,scale:2,buttons:{contextButton:{className:"highcharts-contextbutton",menuClassName:"highcharts-contextmenu",symbol:"menu",_titleKey:"contextButtonTitle",menuItems:[{textKey:"printChart",onclick:function(){this.print()}},{separator:!0},{textKey:"downloadPNG",onclick:function(){this.exportChart()}},{textKey:"downloadJPEG",onclick:function(){this.exportChart({type:"image/jpeg"})}},
{textKey:"downloadPDF",onclick:function(){this.exportChart({type:"application/pdf"})}},{textKey:"downloadSVG",onclick:function(){this.exportChart({type:"image/svg+xml"})}}]}}};f.post=function(a,c,e){var b;a=q("form",p({method:"post",action:a,enctype:"multipart/form-data"},e),{display:"none"},n.body);for(b in c)q("input",{type:"hidden",name:b,value:c[b]},null,a);a.submit();B(a)};r(A.prototype,{sanitizeSVG:function(a,c){if(c&&c.exporting&&c.exporting.allowHTML){var e=a.match(/<\/svg>(.*?$)/);e&&(e=
'\x3cforeignObject x\x3d"0" y\x3d"0" width\x3d"'+c.chart.width+'" height\x3d"'+c.chart.height+'"\x3e\x3cbody xmlns\x3d"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"\x3e'+e[1]+"\x3c/body\x3e\x3c/foreignObject\x3e",a=a.replace("\x3c/svg\x3e",e+"\x3c/svg\x3e"))}a=a.replace(/zIndex="[^"]+"/g,"").replace(/isShadow="[^"]+"/g,"").replace(/symbolName="[^"]+"/g,"").replace(/jQuery[0-9]+="[^"]+"/g,"").replace(/url\(("|&quot;)(\S+)("|&quot;)\)/g,"url($2)").replace(/url\([^#]+#/g,"url(#").replace(/<svg /,'\x3csvg xmlns:xlink\x3d"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" ').replace(/ (NS[0-9]+\:)?href=/g,
" xlink:href\x3d").replace(/\n/," ").replace(/<\/svg>.*?$/,"\x3c/svg\x3e").replace(/(fill|stroke)="rgba\(([ 0-9]+,[ 0-9]+,[ 0-9]+),([ 0-9\.]+)\)"/g,'$1\x3d"rgb($2)" $1-opacity\x3d"$3"').replace(/&nbsp;/g,"\u00a0").replace(/&shy;/g,"\u00ad");return a=a.replace(/<IMG /g,"\x3cimage ").replace(/<(\/?)TITLE>/g,"\x3c$1title\x3e").replace(/height=([^" ]+)/g,'height\x3d"$1"').replace(/width=([^" ]+)/g,'width\x3d"$1"').replace(/hc-svg-href="([^"]+)">/g,'xlink:href\x3d"$1"/\x3e').replace(/ id=([^" >]+)/g,' id\x3d"$1"').replace(/class=([^" >]+)/g,
'class\x3d"$1"').replace(/ transform /g," ").replace(/:(path|rect)/g,"$1").replace(/style="([^"]+)"/g,function(a){return a.toLowerCase()})},getChartHTML:function(){return this.container.innerHTML},getSVG:function(a){var c,e,b,w,m,g=p(this.options,a);n.createElementNS||(n.createElementNS=function(a,c){return n.createElement(c)});e=q("div",null,{position:"absolute",top:"-9999em",width:this.chartWidth+"px",height:this.chartHeight+"px"},n.body);b=this.renderTo.style.width;m=this.renderTo.style.height;
b=g.exporting.sourceWidth||g.chart.width||/px$/.test(b)&&parseInt(b,10)||600;m=g.exporting.sourceHeight||g.chart.height||/px$/.test(m)&&parseInt(m,10)||400;r(g.chart,{animation:!1,renderTo:e,forExport:!0,renderer:"SVGRenderer",width:b,height:m});g.exporting.enabled=!1;delete g.data;g.series=[];k(this.series,function(a){w=p(a.userOptions,{animation:!1,enableMouseTracking:!1,showCheckbox:!1,visible:a.visible});w.isInternal||g.series.push(w)});k(this.axes,function(a){a.userOptions.internalKey=f.uniqueKey()});
c=new f.Chart(g,this.callback);a&&k(["xAxis","yAxis","series"],function(b){var d={};a[b]&&(d[b]=a[b],c.update(d))});k(this.axes,function(a){var b=f.find(c.axes,function(b){return b.options.internalKey===a.userOptions.internalKey}),d=a.getExtremes(),e=d.userMin,d=d.userMax;!b||void 0===e&&void 0===d||b.setExtremes(e,d,!0,!1)});b=c.getChartHTML();b=this.sanitizeSVG(b,g);g=null;c.destroy();B(e);return b},getSVGForExport:function(a,c){var e=this.options.exporting;return this.getSVG(p({chart:{borderRadius:0}},
e.chartOptions,c,{exporting:{sourceWidth:a&&a.sourceWidth||e.sourceWidth,sourceHeight:a&&a.sourceHeight||e.sourceHeight}}))},exportChart:function(a,c){c=this.getSVGForExport(a,c);a=p(this.options.exporting,a);f.post(a.url,{filename:a.filename||"chart",type:a.type,width:a.width||0,scale:a.scale,svg:c},a.formAttributes)},print:function(){var a=this,c=a.container,e=[],b=c.parentNode,f=n.body,m=f.childNodes,g=a.options.exporting.printMaxWidth,d,t;if(!a.isPrinting){a.isPrinting=!0;a.pointer.reset(null,
0);D(a,"beforePrint");if(t=g&&a.chartWidth>g)d=[a.options.chart.width,void 0,!1],a.setSize(g,void 0,!1);k(m,function(a,b){1===a.nodeType&&(e[b]=a.style.display,a.style.display="none")});f.appendChild(c);E.focus();E.print();setTimeout(function(){b.appendChild(c);k(m,function(a,b){1===a.nodeType&&(a.style.display=e[b])});a.isPrinting=!1;t&&a.setSize.apply(a,d);D(a,"afterPrint")},1E3)}},contextMenu:function(a,c,e,b,f,m,g){var d=this,t=d.options.navigation,w=d.chartWidth,h=d.chartHeight,p="cache-"+a,
l=d[p],x=Math.max(f,m),y,z;l||(d[p]=l=q("div",{className:a},{position:"absolute",zIndex:1E3,padding:x+"px"},d.container),y=q("div",{className:"highcharts-menu"},null,l),v(y,r({MozBoxShadow:"3px 3px 10px #888",WebkitBoxShadow:"3px 3px 10px #888",boxShadow:"3px 3px 10px #888"},t.menuStyle)),z=function(){v(l,{display:"none"});g&&g.setState(0);d.openMenu=!1},u(l,"mouseleave",function(){l.hideTimer=setTimeout(z,500)}),u(l,"mouseenter",function(){clearTimeout(l.hideTimer)}),p=u(n,"mouseup",function(b){d.pointer.inClass(b.target,
a)||z()}),u(d,"destroy",p),k(c,function(a){if(a){var b;a.separator?b=q("hr",null,null,y):(b=q("div",{className:"highcharts-menu-item",onclick:function(b){b&&b.stopPropagation();z();a.onclick&&a.onclick.apply(d,arguments)},innerHTML:a.text||d.options.lang[a.textKey]},null,y),b.onmouseover=function(){v(this,t.menuItemHoverStyle)},b.onmouseout=function(){v(this,t.menuItemStyle)},v(b,r({cursor:"pointer"},t.menuItemStyle)));d.exportDivElements.push(b)}}),d.exportDivElements.push(y,l),d.exportMenuWidth=
l.offsetWidth,d.exportMenuHeight=l.offsetHeight);c={display:"block"};e+d.exportMenuWidth>w?c.right=w-e-f-x+"px":c.left=e-x+"px";b+m+d.exportMenuHeight>h&&"top"!==g.alignOptions.verticalAlign?c.bottom=h-b-x+"px":c.top=b+m-x+"px";v(l,c);d.openMenu=!0},addButton:function(a){var c=this,e=c.renderer,b=p(c.options.navigation.buttonOptions,a),f=b.onclick,m=b.menuItems,g,d,h=b.symbolSize||12;c.btnCount||(c.btnCount=0);c.exportDivElements||(c.exportDivElements=[],c.exportSVGElements=[]);if(!1!==b.enabled){var k=
b.theme,n=k.states,q=n&&n.hover,n=n&&n.select,l;delete k.states;f?l=function(a){a.stopPropagation();f.call(c,a)}:m&&(l=function(){c.contextMenu(d.menuClassName,m,d.translateX,d.translateY,d.width,d.height,d);d.setState(2)});b.text&&b.symbol?k.paddingLeft=C(k.paddingLeft,25):b.text||r(k,{width:b.width,height:b.height,padding:0});d=e.button(b.text,0,0,l,k,q,n).addClass(a.className).attr({"stroke-linecap":"round",title:c.options.lang[b._titleKey],zIndex:3});d.menuClassName=a.menuClassName||"highcharts-menu-"+
c.btnCount++;b.symbol&&(g=e.symbol(b.symbol,b.symbolX-h/2,b.symbolY-h/2,h,h).addClass("highcharts-button-symbol").attr({zIndex:1}).add(d),g.attr({stroke:b.symbolStroke,fill:b.symbolFill,"stroke-width":b.symbolStrokeWidth||1}));d.add().align(r(b,{width:d.width,x:C(b.x,c.buttonOffset)}),!0,"spacingBox");c.buttonOffset+=(d.width+b.buttonSpacing)*("right"===b.align?-1:1);c.exportSVGElements.push(d,g)}},destroyExport:function(a){var c=a?a.target:this;a=c.exportSVGElements;var e=c.exportDivElements;a&&
(k(a,function(a,e){a&&(a.onclick=a.ontouchstart=null,c.exportSVGElements[e]=a.destroy())}),a.length=0);e&&(k(e,function(a,e){clearTimeout(a.hideTimer);F(a,"mouseleave");c.exportDivElements[e]=a.onmouseout=a.onmouseover=a.ontouchstart=a.onclick=null;B(a)}),e.length=0)}});H.menu=function(a,c,e,b){return["M",a,c+2.5,"L",a+e,c+2.5,"M",a,c+b/2+.5,"L",a+e,c+b/2+.5,"M",a,c+b-1.5,"L",a+e,c+b-1.5]};A.prototype.renderExporting=function(){var a,c=this.options.exporting,e=c.buttons,b=this.isDirtyExporting||!this.exportSVGElements;
this.buttonOffset=0;this.isDirtyExporting&&this.destroyExport();if(b&&!1!==c.enabled){for(a in e)this.addButton(e[a]);this.isDirtyExporting=!1}u(this,"destroy",this.destroyExport)};A.prototype.callbacks.push(function(a){a.renderExporting();u(a,"redraw",a.renderExporting);k(["exporting","navigation"],function(c){a[c]={update:function(e,b){a.isDirtyExporting=!0;p(!0,a.options[c],e);C(b,!0)&&a.redraw()}}})})})(h)});
```

Could anyone suggest me ways to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share your "exporting.js" file code

Comment: Hi ricky, I have made an edit in the post to provide a link to the exporting.js file.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the latest exporting module of HighCharts?

Comment: @Infinite007 where is link ? Better you post the code here

Comment: Yes Anna, I have used the latest version.

Comment: Hi ricky, link to the file : https://1drv.ms/f/s!AipQvTcKsUCnad8dnD39jNsLbXk

Comment: Highcharts is a browser charting library - it requires dom/window environment - so you won't be able to generate charts in the node environment unless you use some kind of virtual-dom library, e.g. jsdom.